# Lebesgue Outer Measure Additivity for disjoint intervals.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

I am trying to prove that if $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}I_i$ are disjoint open intervals then
$$|\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}I_i|=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{l}(I_i).$$ Where $||$ is the Lebesgue outer measure.

I know that by countable subadditivity we have $$|\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}I_i|\le\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{l}(I_i).$$

For the other direction consider $\epsilon>0$ then by definition of the infimum there must exist $ \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}I_i \subset \cup_{k=1}^{\infty}J_k$ such that

$$|\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}I_i|+ \epsilon \ge\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{l}(J_k)$$.

Consider the covering $I_i\subset\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}J_k\cap I_i$, then
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{l}(J_k\cap I_i)\ge |I_i|.$$

This implies

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{l}(J_k\cap I_i)\ge \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|I_i|=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{l}(I_i).$$
Since
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{l}(J_k)\ge\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{l}(J_k\cap I_i),$$

we get

$$|\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}I_i|+ \epsilon \ge \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{l}(I_i).$$

Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary we get

$$|\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}I_i| \ge \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{l}(I_i).$$

I don't have confidence in my proof abilities. Are there any mistakes in my proof?

Comment: It is not clear why the intervals $I_k$ are trivial for $k >n$.

Comment: @copper.hat That is the one part I was doubting. I figured since the intervals I are disjoint they are breaking up J but they may not include all of J.

Comment: I would split the proof into two cases depending on whether or not $m^*(\cup_n I_n)$ is finite or not. Also, you need to justify that $l(I_i) \le \sum_k l(J_k \cap I_i)$ and $\sum_i l(I_i \cap J_k) \le l(J_k)$.